# External TV hides System Preferences UI

Tags: display, display-resolution

Using Ubuntu 16.04 on a Dell XPS 13" here. When I try to present something on an external TV via HDMI I need to manually set the resolution of the TV. It works but...

The resolution is so bad the `Apply` button of the System Preferences > Screen Display settings is hidden under the screen. Making it impossible to change any of the settings.

Tried with multiple different TVs but always the same problem.

My default res is 3200 x 1800 (it's the XPS HDPI screen). I connect the external TV, it's black. I mirror the screen and drop the resolution to something lower, the screen lights up and I can see my desktop but now the resolution is too low and I can no longer change anything since 50% of the System Preferences window is hidden under the screen.

Anyone?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can either...

- hold down the <kbd>ALT</kbd> key while left-click-hold-drag in the System Preferences window, and move the System Preferences window so that you can hit the Apply button
- make sure that you have 2-4 workspaces enabled, and then switch to workspace 2/3 to be able to see the bottom portion of the System Preferences window so that you can hit the Apply button